# How to convert a returned uint8_u to GoString in ARM?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I call a C function from Go using cgo. The return type of the function is uint8_u *. I know it is a string and need to print it in Go.

I have the following in myFile.go

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "cLogic.h"
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)    

func main() {
    myString := "DUMMY"
    cMyString := C.CString(myString)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cMyString))

    cMyInt := C.int(10)

    cResult := C.MyCFunction(cMyString, cMyInt) // Result is type *_Ctype_schar (int8_t *)
    goResult := C.GoString(cResult)
    fmt.Println("GoResult: " + goResult + "\n")
}
```

In file cLogic.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

int8_t *MyCFunction(char *myString, int myInt);
```

In File cLogic.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

int8_t *MyCFunction(char *myString, int myInt){
    return "this is test";
}
```

I get an error in the line

```
goResult := C.GoString(cResult)
```

> cannot use cResult (type *_Ctype_schar) as type *_Ctype_char in
>   argument to _Cfunc_GoString

I understand it has a casting issue, but if I cast uint8_u * to char * in C it is fine (I'm sure I won't have issues by this cast).

When I cast it on my amd64 pc with "go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64" it builds, although on an arm machine with "go version go1.10.3 linux/arm" I get the error

> cannot convert cResult (type *_Ctype_schar) to type *_Ctype_char

Comment: what if you define your C function as `char * ` instead of uint8_t?

Comment: @P__J__ That works, but I'm using code from third-parties. In that case it needs to be uint8_t.

Comment: But return char *. Do you know C at all?

Comment: I cannot change the third-party's code.

Answer (score 1):

So add the wrapper

wrapper.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

char *mywrapper(char *myString, int myInt);
```

wrapper.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "cLogic.h"

char *mywrapper(char *myString, int myInt);
{
  return (char *)MyCFunction(myString, myInt);
}
```

And include this wrapper ino your go code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a workaround I can live with. Although I would like to know if there is another way without this.. :(